# C# Selenium function still waiting where options is loaded

Tags: c#, selenium

I create wait until ajax load options to select.

I write this code :

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(
           By.CssSelector(idKontrolki + "_dropDownListValues > option:nth-child(1)")));
```

The wait function run for 3 second, despite the options are loaded, it still waiting.

Someone could tell me why?

Comment: What value does idKontrolki have? Does it conform to a selector?

Comment: Yes i copy selector from browser

Comment: But i mean, does it start with '#' if it should be an id?

Comment: Please show HTML code and a value of  `idKontrolki` corresponding to your given HTML.